# Why is the parent value getting updated when I use the scope variable of same name as parent?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I came across the discussion on controller as vs $scope for angular here:-

http://codetunnel.io/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope/

Just to hack into it and understand I created a scope variable with the same name as the parent controller.
I was surprised to see parent controller value getting changed when we change the child value.

Could someone please explain what is happening here.

Link:-http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqMXwo

HTML:-

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <h3>Still works as expected, but without a manaul namespace.</h3>
  <div class="controller" ng-controller="ParentController as parent">
    ParentController: <input type="text" ng-model="parent.foo" />
    foo: {{ parent.foo }}
  <div class="controller" ng-controller="ChildController as child">
    ChildController: <input type="text" ng-model="parent.foo" />
    foo: {{ parent.foo }}
  </div>
</div>

JS:-

function ParentController($scope) {
  this.foo = 'bar';
}
function ChildController($scope) {
  $scope.parent.foo="How did this happen";
}

angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ParentController', ParentController)
    .controller('ChildController', ChildController);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="controller" ng-controller="ChildController as child">
ChildController: <input type="text" ng-model="parent.foo" />
foo: {{ parent.foo }}
</div>
```

I think you should replace the above with the following ControllerAs method. And for code consistency it is better to use either $scope or ControllerAs.

```
<div class="controller" ng-controller="ChildController as child">
ChildController: <input type="text" ng-model="child.parent.foo" />
foo: {{ parent.foo }}
</div>
```

And as i know if you do not want to use ControllerAs method, and want to refer to parent scope in a children controller, you should use "$parent" instead of "parent"